# flask return dataframe table result but unable to show in table

Tags: html, css

new to flask, everything working fine in python, but now stuck at render in flask.
result is working, stucked at the 'showing' part, as i want to return result and show in table

frontend showing:
[image]

backend showing:
[image]

sample code reference @https://github.com/ZhengTzer/resume-scanner

for minimal reproduce code

so hard figuring out flask, which part i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use `<th>` in the first line of `<tr>`

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Just push up arrow on answer and select it as right)

Comment: what i mean is: i upload the photo showing result did come by, it's working, just not showing, and it is not about html